# postgres: is not a valid data directory

Tags: postgresql, linux

I am trying to bring up a postgres server where the configuration files and the data are in separate places/partitions

postgresql-10 has been installed using the official repository using YUM in Centos 7

And it has been initialised using

```
/usr/pgsql-10/bin/pg_ctl initdb --pgdata=/var/lib/pgsql/10/data
```

as user `app`

What is referenced as PGDATA (configuration) directory is the default one:

```
# ls -salt /var/lib/pgsql/10/data
total 120
 4 drwxrwxr-x. 19 app app  4096 Nov 10 17:29 .
```

I would like to use the following directory for data storage:

```
# ls -salt /usr/ip-spotlight/postgresql/
total 12
4 drwxrwxr-x. 3 postgres  postgres  4096 Nov 10 17:43 .
4 drwx------. 2 postgres  postgres  4096 Nov 10 17:43 data
```

And it complains about:

```
2017-11-10 17:51:44.495 CET [81743] FATAL:  "/usr/ip-spotlight/postgresql/data" is not a valid data directory
2017-11-10 17:51:44.495 CET [81743] DETAIL:  File "/usr/ip-spotlight/postgresql/data/PG_VERSION" is missing.
```

On the other hand, in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-file-locations.html it says:

> If you wish, you can specify the configuration file names and
>   locations individually using the parameters config_file, hba_file
>   and/or ident_file. config_file can only be specified on the postgres
>   command line, but the others can be set within the main configuration
>   file.

My `/var/lib/pgsql/10/data/postgresql.conf` is configured as:

```
data_directory = '/usr/ip-spotlight/postgresql/data'
hba_file = '/var/lib/pgsql/10/data/pg_hba.conf'
ident_file = '/var/lib/pgsql/10/data/pg_ident.conf'
```

Could you please advise how to separate the config files of postgresql and the actual data storage ?

Answer (score 3):

OK, i figured it out:

1. initialise the db as user `postgres`

   ```
   name: "Create a new PostgreSQL database cluster"
   become: postgres
   command: "/usr/pgsql-{{ postgres_version.major }}/bin/pg_ctl initdb --pgdata={{ postgres_data }}"
   ignore_errors: yes
   ```
2. override `PGDATA` env variable through systemd

   ```
   name: "Override PGDATA pathname (1/3)"
   become: yes
   file: path="/etc/systemd/system/postgresql-{{ postgres_version.major }}.service" state=touch owner=root group=root mode=0644
   when: dev.platform == "baremetal"
   ```

   ```
   name: "Override PGDATA pathname (2/3)"
   become: yes
   lineinfile: path="/etc/systemd/system/postgresql-{{ postgres_version.major }}.service" line=".include /lib/systemd/system/postgresql-{{ postgres_version.major }}.service" state=present
   when: dev.platform == "baremetal"
   ```

   ```
   name: "Override PGDATA pathname (3/3)"
   become: yes
   blockinfile:
     path: "/etc/systemd/system/postgresql-{{ postgres_version.major }}.service"
     state: present
     block: |
       [Service]
       Environment=PGDATA={{ postgres_data }}
     when: dev.platform == "baremetal"
     notify:
       reload-systemd
   ```